# How to use Cypress fixture data outside of a promise's then() block

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I'm testing Cypress and I have this code for a [custom Cypress command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Syntax):

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (user, password) => {
  if (!user || !password) {
    user = 'user@test.com.br';
    password = '123321';
  }

  cy.visit('');
  cy.contains('Entrar').click();
  cy.get('input[name=_username]')
    .type(user);
  cy.get('input[name=_password]')
    .type(password);
  cy.get('.btn').click();
});
```

If you call `cy.login()` without any arguments, `user` and `password` are assigned within the `if` block.  Otherwise, it uses the passed parameter values.

I tried to add fixtures here, and came up with this code:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (user, password) => {

  if (!user || !password) {

    cy.fixture('users').then((json) => {
      var user, password;

      user = json[0].email;
      password = json[0].password;

      login2(user,password);
    });

  } else {

    login2(user, password);

  }

  function login2(user, password) {

    cy.visit('');
    cy.contains('Entrar').click();
    cy.get('input[name=_username]')
      .type(user);
    cy.get('input[name=_password]')
      .type(password);
    cy.get('.btn').click();

  }
});
```

When I set `user = json[0].email`, it has the value just inside the `.then`,
so I created the function login to fix that.

I imagine there is a better way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Show us the code where you have used login2 please, otherwise it's kind of difficult to provide any opinion

Comment: Sorry, login2 is the last function, mistype

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cypress documentation provides guidance for working with [Return Values](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Return-Values).  Most notably, it advises the following:

> **Return Values**
>
> You cannot assign or work with the return values of any Cypress command. Commands are enqueued and run asynchronously.

The documentation then goes on to explain the use of [Closures](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Closures), and nesting commands inside of the `.then()` block.  Taking advantage of this approach in **cypress/support/commands.js**, you might simplify your code like this:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("login", (user, pw) => {
  let username;
  let password;

  cy.fixture('default-user') // <-- fixture in a separate file, default-user.js
    .then((defaultUser) => {
      username = user || defaultUser.username;
      password = pw || defaultUser.password;

      cy.get('input[name=_username]').type(username);
      cy.get('input[name=_password]').type(password);

      cy.get('.btn').click();
    });
});
```

For reference, **default-user.js** looks like this:

```
{
  username: 'user@test.com.br',
  password: '123321'
}
```

[image: successful test run image]

The Cypress documentation on [Aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Aliases) and [Sharing Context](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Sharing-Context) are helpful for understanding the nuances for referencing values in different Cypress contexts and use cases.